# upload freeware program to ubuntu software center

Tags: software-center, ppa

I am trying to upload a freeware program in ubuntu software center but it says that only paid programms can be uploaded. Why? How do i upload a freeware program.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just upload to Software Center, you need to have your app evaluated, and then once approved, it will be published.

See [Ubuntu Developer](http://developer.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: i already have my app evaluated and published but it's paid i want it to be free, when i try to change the price from 2.99 to FREE it says that i have to  use launchpad and only paid apps are available .